# How to add a character in EditText after user starts typing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an editText where a user inputs a phone number, but right when they click their first number, I want a '+' to appear in the beginning of the text. I have this code but the '+' is constantly there. I only want it to appear when a user inputs a number, how would I fix this?

```
    final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.register_edit_phone);
    final String prefix = "+";
    editText.setText(prefix);
    Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().startsWith(prefix)) {
                editText.setText(prefix);
                Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try checking if `s.toString()` is empty.

Comment: Check this link out, it explains how to do what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958867/enter-character-immediately-after-entering-first-character-in-android

Comment: Why bother with all this complexity? Just add a `TextView` left of the `EditText` with a `+` to show to the user and if you want to store the number with the `+` symbol do it by code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextWatcher`

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Implement it like this. You can also trick it to fit your needs

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // Specify your database function here.
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `OnEditorActionListener` interface to avoid the anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+.*");

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (p.matcher(s.toString().trim()).matches()) {
                editText.setText(prefix + s.toString());
            }
            Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    if (s.length == 1){ 
          if (s.toString().equals("+"))  editText.setText""
          else editText.setText("+"+s.toString)
          }
```

Comment: Please explain your code and how it answers the question.